# solve $c_1, c_2, c_3$ for matrix so that it has infinite solutions and no solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations

let $$A_c = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      2+2c&-4+2c&-4-3c+c^2\\
      1+c&-1+c&-1-c+c^2\\
      -1-c&2-c&2+c\\
    \end{array}
\right) $$

$$ b_c= \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      11-5c\\
      3-2c\\
      -6+3c\\
    \end{array}
\right) $$

How can I define $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb R$ with $c_1 \lt c_2$ so, that 
the linear equationsystems $(A_{c_1}|b_{C_1})$ and $(A_{c_2}|b_{C_2})$ so that they have no solution and also $(A_{c_3}|b_{C_3})$ that is has infinite solutions?

$$ \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2+2c&-4+2c&-4-3c+c^2&11-5c\\
      1+c&-1+c&-1-c+c^2&3-2c\\
      -1-c&2-c&2+c&-6+3c\\
    \end{array}
\right) $$

I know that for infinite solutions two lines have to be equal:

$(1+c)x_1 + (-1+c)x_2+(-1-c+c^2)x_3-3+2c=(-1-c)x_1+(2-c)x_2+(2+c)x_3+6-3c$

$\equiv (2+c)x_1 + (-3+2c)x_2 + (-3-2c+c^2)x_3-9+5c=0$

But how to solve that?

And how can I get the $c_1, c_2$ for the matrices without any solution?

**EDIT:**

I have simplyfied the matrix to 
$$ \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2+2c&-4+2c&-4-3c+c^2&11-5c\\
      0&-2&-2-c-c^2&5-c\\
      0&0&-c+c^2&-1+c\\
    \end{array}
\right) $$

so the $c_1, c_2$ for no solution are $-c+c^2=0 \Rightarrow c=0, c=1$

How can I get $c_3$?

Comment: I suggest that you start by reducing the matrix.This should simplify your result noticeably as many of the elements are exact multiples of each other. Maybe post your martix in its reduced echelon form afterwards, and you might even just see the result once reduction is complete, because you are on the right track basically.

Comment: Also, reduction will expose the condition for which there will be no solution. Note that you must have a contradiction for every choice you make for your variables. What does this independence of the variables say on their coefficients?

Comment: @Yoni Ok, I have updated my post and solved it for the impossible solution. Can you give me any hint for $c_3$?

Comment: No solution and infinitely many solutions are *identical* on the conditions for the coefficients of the reduced matrix. They differ only when you look at the right hand side. Assuming your reduced matrix is correct, then Hint1: $c=0, c=1$ do *not* have the same number of solutions, and Hint2: There is another member of the matrix that depends on $c$ and could cause the system to have no or infinitely many solutions.